# Read Array Length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to perform some task with angularjs, according to JSON array but length property does not work.

```
var st = {
  "user": [{    
    "child":[{
      "label":"Batch Group 1"
    },{
      "label":"Batch Group 2"
    }],
  }]
};

console.log("lenght : "+st.user.child.length);
```

How can i get length of the JSON array?

Comment: What is `st.user`, array? Array. How to access array elements? By index. So try: `st.user[0].child.length`. And it has nothing to do with neither Angular nor JSON.

Comment: try st.user[0].child.length?

Comment: @dfsq `JSON` is short for `JavaScript Object Notation`. Since this is a JavaScript object it obviously has to do with `JSON`

Comment: Dannys answer is correct. This link will help you debug your Javascript in future. Most javascript debuggers are similar. Chrome is my first choice - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools . The sections on working with the console and debugging javascript are useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`user` is an array. The following should work.

```
console.log("lenght : "+st.user[0].child.length);
```